# Звук при клике на ссылку

Tags: javascript

Привет всем! Как замутить звук при клике на ссылку, чтобы во всех обозревателях тема работала?

Comment: Не дай Бог кто расскажет.

Comment: Дело в том, что в 0,01% случаев таки НАДО чтобы был звук. Например, щелчок при получении сообщения. Другое дело, по правилам хорошего тона, такие вещи делают отключаемыми и по-умолчанию отключенными. Кроме того, звук должен быть коротким и ненавязчивым.

Comment: [How to play sound onclick link][1]

*"ту мильйон долларс? нипанятна)"*


  [1]: http://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=play+sound+from+click+link&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#pq=how+to+play+sound+onclick+in+html&hl=ru&cp=30&gs_id=4o&xhr=t&q=how+to+play+sound+onclick+link&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&client=opera&hs=FSd&rls=ru&channel=suggest&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=how+to+play+sound+onclick+link&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=c097dfc250a9cd43&biw=1366&bih=685

Comment: Не издевайся. Я полгода работал в конторе, где был отличный программер, в корень не знающий английского. У меня у самого с треском порвался шаблон.

Comment: Я полагаю что JS от английского отличить можно)))

Comment: Да. Кстати, я оттуда же скопировал. XD

Answer (score 3):

Я - предатель.

```
<a href="mysite.com" onclick="playSound('myClickSound.mid')">Click me:)</a>

<div id="mysoundEl"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function playSound(soundfile) {
 document.getElementById("mysoundEl").innerHTML=
 "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
 }
</script>
```

Ах, да. Пользователи вас возненавидят © Я

Comment: `playSound` вернет true, и произойдет переход по ссылке, соответственно звук не успеет воспроизвестись. Тут похоже придется делать что-то синхронно-асинхронное: клик на ссылке -> подгружаем звук -> воспроизводим звук -> переход по ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на основе Flash:

```
function playWave(sound) {
    $("#wave").remove()
    $('body').append("<embed id='wave' autostart='true' hidden='true' src='sound.wav' />");
}
```